# Out of memory error with netbeans and eclipse

Tags: netbeans, ide, ubuntu

I created a c++ project in netbeans and I am getting an out of memory error on Ubuntu 10.10. I tried increasing the heap space in netbeans.conf file. But it didn't work. Same problem with eclipse as well.

Can someone suggest any good workaround or alternate IDEs for C++ development ?

Comment: Can u be mo specific about when and how you got the error, and the hardware ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's an IDE issue and not an programmatic one? Did you already check for Invalid memory access, memory leaks, doubly freeing the memory, using new for memory allocation and delete for freeing up, any thread accessing stack memory of a different thread?

Comment: It's an IDE issue.It occurs when I create a new project. It is giving this error during the parsing and analyzing phase. May be too many files ?  I am running Ubuntu 10.10 on a HP pavilion laptop (4 GB RAM, 64 bit, dual core).